# XEP-0163 support and mod_pubsub configuration

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am using ejabberd 20.04 on a Gentoo server and I am having difficulties to get XEP-0163 (Personal Eventing Protocol) to work again. I am writing "again" because it worked, at some point. But my setup dates back to 2009, with version 2.something...

So first, here are the relevant current configuration bits in my `ejabberd.yml` configuration file.

```yaml
modules:
  ...
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_pubsub:
    access_create_node: local
    default_node_config:
      notification_type: normal
      notify_retract: false
      max_items: 10
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep

append_host_config:
  "MYSERVER.COM":
    modules:
      mod_register:
        access:
          - deny
    ...
    auth_method: external
    extauth_program: "/path/to/some/script/ejabberd.py"
```

Everything is working fine but using Psi+ (v1.5.1477 on Windows for now), when setting my mood for instance, I got this reply:

```xml
<iq id="aca5a" type="set">
  <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
    <publish node="http://jabber.org/protocol/mood">
      <item id="current">
        <mood xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/mood">
          <sick/>
          <text>Grrrr</text>
        </mood>
      </item>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
</iq>

<iq to="ME@MYSERVER.COM/Psi+" xml:lang="fr"
    from="ME@MYSERVER.COM" id="aca5a" type="error">
  <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
    <publish node="http://jabber.org/protocol/mood">
      <item id="current">
        <mood xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/mood">
          <sick/>
          <text>Grrrr</text>
        </mood>
      </item>
    </publish>
  </pubsub>
  <error code="403" type="auth">
    <forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

I thought it was an issue with the ACL so I tried to replace it with:

```yaml
    access_create_node:
      allow: all
```

But I still have the same reply. So I understand there is an auth issue, but I don't understand what.

Can it be an issue with the external auth ? It is working fine for everything else and I don't see any error in the script log (something I wrote which outputs some logs about what ejabberd is requesting).

(Not sure my question belongs here, my guess is it would better suits Serverfault but ProcessOne is redirecting here.)

Answer (score 0):

I installed ejabberd 20.04, configured mod_pubsub like you, and set as extauth program the example checl_pass_null.pl

Then I send your same IQ stanza, and ejabberd replies correctly.

You can try with that extauth script, if it works correctly, then something is missing in your extauth script.

If it still fails with the example check_pass_null.pl, then the problem may be in some other change you made to the default configuration. You can try to use the default configuration (with barely minimum changes). If it works then, you can investigate what of your custom options break pubsub.

Comment: I tried with the `check_pass_null.pl` script and it is still not working. Actually, there is not even a single entry in the log for it.
I edited the config and reloaded it (`ejabberdctl reload_config`), saw the script being launched in the log, me authenticating but then, when trying to set my mood, nothing. And still the same error stanza response.

Is it normal nothing is passed to the auth script when trying to set mood, tune... ?

Comment: I will try with default config, but I would like to save the mnesia database before. Clean start.

Comment: The auth script is used when XMPP client logins, changes password, or deletes the account. Setting mood is unrelated to the authentication method, right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @badlop; that's what I thought. So my issue should lie in the configuration. When I have a couple hours, I'll try to save the DB, my config and start from scratch.